# python check for duplicates by reversing strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys in the following form:

```
d['a:b']
d['c:d']
d['e:f']
d['d:c']
d['b:a']
d['f:e']
```

How can I check for and remove duplicates, where a duplicate would be

```
d['a:b'] = d['b:a']
```

so after checking and removing, the dictionary would consist of

```
d['a:b']
d['c:d']
d['e:f']
```

Comment: just for clarification, `d` is your dictionary right?

Comment: @RNar Yes, d is the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d.keys() return a copy, so items can be popped.

```
d = { k:None for k in  ('a:b','c:d','e:f','d:c','b:a','f:e') }
for k in d.keys():
    if '{}:{}'.format(k[2],k[0]) in d:
        d.pop(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unique = []
delete = []
for key in d.keys():
  if key[::-1] in unique:
    delete.append(key)
  else:
    unique.append(key)
for key in delete: del d[key]
```

not very nice with the two loops, but works

Answer (score -1):

```
unique = []
for key in sorted(d.keys()):
    if key in unique or key[-1] + key[1] + key[0] in unique:
        d.pop(key)
    unique.append(key)
print d
```